# How to get all the month last date in the fiscal year using sql

Tags: sql, date

I specify my input as `'jun - may'`.

Checking the current year and month:

1. If the current month is SEPTEMBER (9) and the current year is 2014, then the fiscal year is set to `June 2014 - May 2015`.
2. If the current month is JANUARY (1) and the current year is 2014, then the fiscal year is set to `Jun 2013 - May 2014`.

I need to find the last date of every month within the fiscal year.

I found the solution for getting the last date of a month, but don't know how to extend that to find all the months within the range depending upon the logic.

My try so far:

```
DECLARE @Month int
DECLARE @Year int

set @Month = 2
set @Year = 2004

select DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month,@Month,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0)))
```

Comment: So, if the current month is between `June to December` say **2014** then fiscal year is `June 2014 to May 2015`. However, if the current month is between `January to May` say **2014** again, the fiscal year is `June 2013 to May 2014`? Is that correct?

Comment: Xcatly you are rite !!!!

Comment: So, how should the output looks like by the way? And to what value should I compared the extracted range? Let's say I get June 2014 to May 2015 to which value (or field?) should I compare it? Or do I need to put the ranges of values from June 2014, July 2014, August 2014 until May 2015 in a table?

Comment: Yes Edper. I got the solution from the below answer, thank you for spending your valuable time. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
DECLARE @Month int =5
DECLARE @Year int = 2004
declare @i int = 0
if @Month between 1 and 5  set @i = 1 else set @i = 0
create table #temp(Monthend datetime)

set @Month = 6
while(@month<=12)
begin
insert into #temp
select DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month,@Month,DATEADD(year,@Year-@i-1900,0)))  
set @month = @month+1
end

set @Month = 1
while(@month<6)
begin
insert into #temp
select DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month,@Month,DATEADD(year,@Year-@i-1899,0)))  
set @month = @month+1
end

Select * from #temp
Drop table #temp
```

Comment: Thank you legend :) I cant able to give +10, so i gave +1